# json_encode retornando vazio

Tags: php, ajax, pdo

Estou realizando uma consulta básica no banco, usando o seguinte código:

```
public function searchAllProducts(){
    $array = array();
    $select = $this->connection->prepare("Select * from tb_produto");
    $select->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $select->execute();
    $produtos = $select->fetchAll();

    foreach ($produtos as $produto) {
      $product = new Produto($produto['IDProduto'], $produto['NomeProduto'], $produto['PrecoProduto'], $produto['DTValProduto'], $produto['QtdProduto'], $produto['DescricaoProduto']);
      array_push($array, $product);
    }
    return $array;
  }
```

O problema é que quando transformo o array em json, usando o `json_encode`, desta forma:

```
require_once '../connection.php';
require_once '../class/ProdutoDAO.php';

$dao = new ProdutoDAO($connection);
$produtos = $dao->searchAllProducts();
//var_dump($produtos);

$json = json_encode($produtos);

echo $json;
```

Isto me retorna `[{},{}]`.

> OBS: O array está preenchido, quando dou um `var_dump($produtos)`, é
>   mostrado os produtos como esperado.

Comment: `Produto()` é um classe com atributos privados e gets para acessá-los?

Comment: Posta ai o que tem dentro do array de retorno

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece pois você está tentando transformar seu objeto em formato Json, `json_encode` só vai funcionar por padrão em tipos primitivos e nos campos `public` dos objetos.

Para que o json_encode funcione, implemente a interface `JsonSerializable`, método `jsonSerialize`, e é isto que você precisa fazer para seu objeto Produto produza alguma saída sem transformar todas as propriedades em `public`.

### Exemplo

```
class Fruit implements JsonSerializable {
    public
        $type = 'Apple',
        $lastEaten = null;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->lastEaten = new DateTime();
    }

    public function jsonSerialize() {
        return [
            'type' => $this->type,
            'lastEaten' => $this->lastEaten->format(DateTime::ISO8601)
        ];
    }
}
echo json_encode(new Fruit()); //which outputs: {"type":"Apple","lastEaten":"2013-01-31T11:17:07-0500"}
```

### Mais informações

- [JsonSerializable::jsonSerialize](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/jsonserializable.jsonserialize.php)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/4697671/266569

Comment: Obrigado ! (deveria existir um gson pra php :/)

Comment: Veja se esse ajuda: https://github.com/tebru/gson-php

Comment: Obrigado novamente !